# bitcode bundle could not be generated because of a framework

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

My application[image] builds properly when I try to run it on a device. Now, I need to generate IPA file to distribute it across devices. I am trying to archive the build but it says an error as shown in attached screenshot. I've been trying to solve this for past three hours but could not.

How do I solve this? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: On disabling the bitcode, I get bunch of errors as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152528/discussion-between-abhishek-thapliyal-and-vamshi-krishna).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Choose the generic iOS device .
2. Build the app .
3. Follow the Archive steps

I got same problem, when I did above steps, then it solved.

Comment: Tried it all but no luck!

Comment: change your bitcode  no and close Xcode then restart the Mac

Comment: I think you are using any framework or library ,which is sports only 32 bit  ,right ?